# Не доступны для редактирования ячейки таблицы в FastReport

Tags: c#, fastreport

Проблема возникла после обновления FastReport.

Ячейка, в которой изначально не указано значение, при клике на неё не подаёт никаких признаков активности, но после клика и ввода какого-то значения, они начинает расширяться.

[Gif](http://recordit.co/1iihIc8Fti)

Но если задать ей какое-то значение изначально, например пробел, то все в порядке.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как решили её? Вариант с пробелом не очень нравится.

Comment: Некоторые html елементы становятся "недействительными" если в них пусто. Например если написать `<div style=background:black;width:100px;> </div>` и `<div style=background:black;width:100px;>&nbsp;</div>` то будет видно что стиль в первом случае игнорируется. Как это правильно обьяснить - незнаю. Рекомендую для пустых елементов с странным поведением добавлять `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В новой версии FastReport'a для текстовых полей было добавлено свойство `TextRenderType`. Т.к. ячейка наследуется от текстового поля, то ей доступно это свойство.

Установка значением `HtmlParagraph` решает эту проблему, но при  экспорте в excel превращает некоторые ячейки в картинки.

Если ячеек много и вручную менять значение проблематично, можно воспользоваться кодом:

```
var tableCells =
            report.AllObjects.ToArray().Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(TableCell)).Cast<TableCell>();

foreach (var tableCell in tableCells)
{
    tableCell.TextRenderType = TextRenderType.HtmlParagraph;
}
```

Но выполнить его перед методом `Prepare()` и после загрузки шаблона документа.

**UPD.**

Поправлено в версии 2019.1.11 FastReport'a.